# How do I compare a single value from a dictionary to a single value in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
 my_dict = {   'order1': ['10','20','30'],   'order2': ['11','12','13'] }
```

I have this pandas dataframe:

| SKU | Location |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 00-2 |
| 30 | 00-3 |
| 3 | 00-0 |

I want to loop through the dictionary, and check if the items in each order (for example order1 has 10, 20 and 30) are in the DF, and if they are, where is their location? Then, I want to add this new information to a dictionary like so:

```
new_dict = { 'order1': ['00-2','00-3'] }
```

This is the code:

```
col = df['SKU'].tolist()

col_str = [str(x) for x in col]
locs = []
for key, value in my_dict.items():
  for i in range(len(value)):
    if value[i] in col_str:
      locs.append(df.loc[df['SKU'] == value[i],"Location"])       
      new_dict[key] = locs
    else:
      print("no")
```

I either get invalid type comparison, False or this error message when I remove the `df['SKU'] == value[i]` to replace it with just the value:

> KeyError: 'the label [10] is not in the [index]'

Answer (score 2):

Create another mapping dictionary from the dataframe

```
sku_dict = dict(zip(df.SKU.astype(str), df.Location))
```

Then just get the key from this dictionary

```
{k: [sku_dict.get(item) for item in v if sku_dict.get(item)] for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```

Output

```
{'order1': ['00-2', '00-3'], 'order2': []}
```

Comment: The values are not integers, though. Some have letters in them, such as "1000A3" - would that cause issues?

Comment: Updated answer @YektaKhalili

Comment: Again, run into the same issue on my real dataset - "arrays must all be same length"

Comment: Just use the dict comprehension

Comment: @YektaKhalili I'm sure that error is because your `my_dict` has varied length lists in it. For example `my_dict = {'order1': ['1'], 'order2': ['1','2']}`. It's better if you create a reproducible with this kind of data.

Comment: @Ch3steR I removed the dataframe solution after taking into consideration the varied length list. The current solution works.

Comment: @Ch3steR not only that, my dataframe is also about 50 rows of SKU's and each order has at most 10 items in it. I will read up on dict comprehension, but I've never heard of reproducible. Could you please guide me towards a good tutorial?

Comment: @Vishnudev YES! That works, thank you so much.

Comment: @YektaKhalili Reproducible is just a sample input data frame you create for us to work on it. It's just the StackOverflow thing. You can read more it [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can apply lambda to get the dictionary key, then explode the order, and groupby order and call agg to form list of orders finaly to_dict() will give you the dictionary.

```py
output=(df.assign(order=df['SKU']
        .astype(str)
        .apply(lambda x: [key for key in my_dict if x in my_dict[key]]))
        .explode('order')
        .groupby('order')['Location'].agg(list)
         .to_dict()
 )

# output
{'order1': ['00-2', '00-3']}
```